# Не загружать блок в мобильной версии

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, bootstrap, media-queries

Есть достаточно длинный лендинг, верстка на bootstrap.
На нем есть несколько блоков с изображениями, которые не должны отображаться на экранах < 992px
Как сделать чтобы эти блоки вообще не подгружались, тем самым уменьшали время загрузки страницы на моб.. Желательно способ без js, но если такого нет, то подойдет и с js.

Comment: чтобы вообще не подгружались их надо добавлять или не добавлять через скрипт, к сожалению по другому никак, в других случаях они будут подгружатся

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В html5 появился новый тег picture, который позволяет не просто скрывать/открывать разные изображения для разных размеров экрана, но именно не допускать их загрузки (в отличие от скрытия с помощью css). Чтобы убедиться в этом, откройте в отладчике Chrome вкладку Network и проследите за загрузкой ресурсов.

```html
<picture>
  <source srcset="https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-pdb/2049822/b2063185-8541-4936-9cfa-5f49ce6b855c/s1200" media="(min-width: 991px)">
  <source srcset="https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-pdb/1043578/97c87fa8-e5ce-4add-8b6d-3952cf90f822/s1200" media="(min-width: 767px)">
  <source srcset="https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-pdb/1748217/795c690e-e9b1-4e2f-93cc-6449379679b5/s1200" media="(min-width: 575px)">
  <img src="" alt="">
</picture>
```

Comment: Хм, интересно... Попробую